# I need to change/remove some CSS call links from wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I need to change/remove some CSS call links. I can see them in View Page Source. How do I actually get to them to make the changes? In other words, where are they?

Comment: the link is something like http://my-website-name/wp-content/cache/minify/f2f65.default.include.857f20.css

Answer (score 0):

Might be This is because of cache plugin in WordPress site. Try to disable CSS minify setting from the plugin.

You can not change those links or remove it but after disabling minify setting you can modify your CSS. You can then find your correct CSS path in view source.

Answer (score 0):

They are either in your theme or in plugins. Most cases it is in themes. open your theme search for the name...there will be a function enque_script with having those file names as parameter. comment the function which is including your unwanted file.